# How to select number of affected rows to variable in function?

Tags: postgresql

```
create or replace function test()
returns void as $$
begin
  update tbl set col1 = true where col2 = false;
  -- now I want to raise exception if update query affected more than 2 rows to rollback the update
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

How I can select number of affected rows to a variable in function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
create or replace function test()
returns void as $$
declare
    v_cnt numeric;
begin
    v_cnt := 0;

        update tbl set col1 = true where col2 = false;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS v_cnt = ROW_COUNT;

        if v_cnt > 1 then
           RAISE EXCEPTION 'more than one row affected --> %', v_cnt; 
        end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hmm as far as I know rows may change between `select count(*)` and `update` because rows are not locked in this transaction... So even if count will return 10 there is no guarantee that exactly 10 rows will be updated. It would require to `select ... for update` but then I would have to make 3 queries because `for update` does not work with aggregate function afaik

Comment: Once you use PL/pgSQL, there is the `ROW_COUNT` variable: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS Furthermore, with the default isolation level (`READ COMMITTED`), there are chances that you count one row and then update two (the second one being committed after the `SELECT` succeeds).

Comment: so `UPDATE ...` and then `GET ... ROW_COUNT` is the way right. UPDATE will automatically lock the rows in current transaction?

Comment: @user606521 yup, thats the best way.