# How can I make UPDATE to return an error if no rows are affected in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, update

In my application code, I have an ordinary UPDATE statement to update some row's properties. However, I've encountered a bug where this statement was provided with an incorrect ID and no row was affected.

This bug was silent because UPDATE statement that affects no rows still finishes successfully. I want to prevent such bugs in the future, and to do so, I want to instantly and loudly fail if this happens. One option that I have is to include a RETURNING statement and check it in the application code, but before going with it (and updating the whole application codebase where this pattern occurs — which is a massive change), I wanted to check the alternatives.

Is there a way to write an UPDATE statement in such a way that it produces an error if now rows are affected?

Comment: you can tgry to use a function  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131826/190821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be possible to put the UPDATE into a CTE and then do something with the number of results:

```
WITH cte AS (
  UPDATE ...
  RETURNING ...
)
SELECT 1 / COUNT(*) FROM cte;
```

If the division by zero is too obscure for you, write a function that raises a proper error.

Personally, I would use a plain UPDATE, and then in my application, wrap all such SQL calls in a function that checks the number of rows. (PG returns that number from every UPDATE, but not every database driver supports this.)